# JSON object is not being rendered in charts js: Django

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, django, chart.js

I have implemented chart JS 2.5 into my django application version 1.11 but I am able to see only the canvas but not any bar chart, besides,the web browser console does not display any error, so this is becoming quite difficult for me to trace the mistake.

[image]

**statistics.html** and **views.py** are my main files where I am currently trying to debug this problem. The **urls.py** and **header.html** files were not touched recently and I put them at the end.

**statistics.html file**:
Graph implementation and retrieval of the JSON object

```
{% extends "personal_website/header.html"%}
<script>
{% block jquery %}
var endpoint = '/statistics/data' 
var defaultData = []
var labels = []
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: endpoint,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        labels = data.labels
        defaultData = data.default
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart")
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type:'bar',
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets : [{
                    label: '# of votes',
                    data: defaultData,
                }]
            }
        })
    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error on data")
        console.log(error_data)
    }
})
{% endblock %}
</script>
{% block content %}

<div class ='row'>
<div class="col-sm-12" url-endpoint='{% url "get_data" %}'>
    <h1>Statistics for week 21</h1>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>     
</div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**Views.py**

get_data() was used to test if I could receive the JSON object through the web browser console.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

def index(request):
   return render(request, 'personal_website/home.html')

def statistics(request):
   return render(request, 'personal_website/statistics.html',{})

def get_data(request, *args, **kwargs):
   response_data = {}
   response_data["customers"] = 100
   response_data["sales"] = 40  *12
   return JsonResponse(response_data)

class ChartData(APIView):

   def get(self,request,format=None):
       labels = ["Red","Blue","Yellow","Green","Purple","Orange"]
       default_items = [22,35,12,8,10,9]
       data = {
           "labels": labels,
           "default": default_items,
       } 
       return Response(data)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views
from .views import ChartData, get_data
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'), # home
    url(r'^statistics/$', views.statistics, name='statistics'),
    url(r'^statistics/data$', get_data, name='get_data'), 
    url(r'^statistics/chart-data$', ChartData.as_view()), # API View working) ]
```

**header.html**

```
<head>
<title>Statistics</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
{% load staticfiles %}
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body class="body" style="background-color:#f6f6f6">
<div class="container-fluid" style="min-height:95%; ">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-10">
          <h3>Statistics</h3>
       </div>
     </div><hr>
     <div class="well bs-sidebar" id="sidebar">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
           <li><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
           <li><a href='/statistics/'>Statistics</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
</div>            
<footer>
    <!-- no content for the moment-->   
</footer>   
</body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js">
    </script>
</html>
```

Lastly, the only part that I see that changes is is the label: '# of votes' from the dataset.

What is missing in the code, so I can see the displayed bar charts?

Any help, suggestion, improvement, question is welcome.

Comment: Please use developer tools network tab to examine your AJAX requests/responses.  Under `class ChartData(APIView):` do you not want to `return JsonResponse(data)` ?

Comment: Under ChartData I get a JSON object in my browser when I use the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/statistics/chart-data when I use the return Response(data) but if I use the return JsonResponse(data), nothing comes up.